# How to push an export from SP List to Sql Server

Tags: export, sync

I would like to export a Sharepoint 2013 Standard list to a Sql Server table regulary without the need of SSIS. In best case they should stay in sync (with some latency of course) but it's just needed for 1-way (SP -> SQL)

I heard of BCS but thought that's only to plug in an external source (Sql table) to sharepoint (not vice versa)

How can I implement that? (It's an existing Sharepoint site)

Comment: What's the version and edition of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a SharePoint timer job + server side code to periodically move the SP List content to a designated SQL table.  Another would be to set a Powershell script to copy your list content to a SQL table and schedule that via a Windows scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Erik makes some good suggestions and without knowing about the table and which version of SharePoint you are running I'd suggest you try using [BCS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx). It's pretty easy to set up and you can control permissions just like a regular SharePoint list. But with BCS there would be no need for a sync job as the table would be surfaced directly into the list.

If you have any further questions about BCS, just add them to your original question.